# file_exists returns false on XAMPP

Tags: php, xampp

I have XAMPP installed on a widows 7 machine and if I execute: `file_exists("ss.txt")` I get true `(ss.txt is in my docroot e:\www\)`

If I move ss.txt to e:\www\var and call `file_exists("/var/ss.txt")` I get false but `file_exists("var/ss.txt")` returns true - Why?

I cannot change where to look `("/var/ss.txt")` because that is an entry from the DB and there is a production server running Ubuntu that uses the same data.

Comment: Because `/var/ss.txt` doesn't exist: `/www/var/ss.txt` exists.... The leading `/` indicates an absolute path from the __disk filesystem root__

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've said you can't change the path in your script because it pulls from a database. Just set up the directory structure on your development machine the same way it will be set up on your server. (i.e. Don't create the directory 'e:\www\var', create the directory 'e:\var'.)

As far as the why, as other people have said, '/var/ss.txt' is an absolute path, and 'var/ss.txt' is a relative path.

Answer (score 0):

`/var/ss.txt` corresponds to a path starting at the root of your drive, while `var/ss.txt` is a path starting from where the script is executed (`e:\www\` in your case).

You can tweak the path you get from the db by preceeding it by a dot `.` to indicate the path starts where the script is executed.

```
$path = '/var/ss.txt';
$relativePath = '.' . $path; // equivalent to "./var/ss.txt"
file_exists($relativePath);
```

You can also trim any `/` from the start of your path:

```
$path = '/var/ss.txt';
$relativePath = ltrim($path, '/'); // equivalent to "var/ss.txt"
file_exists($relativePath);
```

[ltrim documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ltrim.php)